# What is correct between the two sentences?

Tags: verbs, copular-verbs, subordinate-clauses

Consider these two versions:

> 1. You can live peacefully without your wants, but your life can be miserable with all your wants within your reach.
> 2. You can live peacefully without your wants, but your life can be miserable with all your wants **are** within your reach.

I am confused whether to include the linking verb *are*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add this linking verb, "are," you have to change the preposition to an adverb (or something similar), for example, "when." If you don't do this, the second sentence is incorrect. If you want to avoid unnecessary changes, just don't use "are" altogether.

Comment: So the first sentence is grammatically correct, right?

Comment: Yes, but the second is not.